# how can i add more space on Table

Tags: tables, spacing, graphics, multirow

My code is here.

```
\begin{table}[t]
 \centering
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|} \hline
Graph $G$ & Graph $H$ & An isomorphism between $G$ and $H$\\ \hline
\multirow{8}{*}{\includegraphics[height=4cm]{Graph_iso_a.eps}} & \multirow{8}{*}{\includegraphics[height=4cm]{Graph_iso_b.eps}} & $f(a)$ = 1\\&& $f(b)$ = 6\\ &&$f(c)$ = 8\\ &&$f(d)$ = 3\\ &&$f(g)$ = 5\\ &&$f(h)$ = 2\\ &&$f(i)$ = 4\\ &&$f(j)$ = 7\\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{Graph isomorphism.}
\end{table}
```

[image]

The problem is that that is not enough space then the line is covered by the image. How can I fix it? Thanks!

Comment: You should see [Column padding in tables](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/31672/5764) which provides ways to stretch a table vertically (and add space) as well as pad it horizontally (if needed).

Comment: try \vspace or \hspace

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You might have a look on our [our starter page](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) if you wish to familiarize yourself further with our format. A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, then they're marked as a code sample. You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (`{}`) or hit Ctrl+K.

Comment: Thank all of you. The way Werner post works well for me!